Why Samba server in Linux has only hosts connected and not clients?
I am confused with the terminology related to configuring Samba server: in networking settings there are only parameters for 'hosts allowed' and 'hosts denied'. It seems, however, that these effectively mean CLIENTS connected to Samba server, but still they are called hosts. Have I understood wrong or is there some good reason for this mess with naming?

"Host" is often a generic name used to indicate a device on the network.  In this case you can think of a host as a client.

In networking terms, a host is any device on the network - ^^^ oh, snap

in virtualization terminology, a Host is a system running one or more Guest virtual Machines.

Both terms are equally correct in this context. 'Host' describes a network entity (often as opposed to a 'router') while 'client' describes a role – a host that makes a connection is a client; a host that receives a connection is a server. So in the context of configuring a server, all hosts connecting to it would by definition be clients, but they also remain 'hosts' in the networking sense (and the SMB server likewise remains a network host).
(The same smb.conf uses the term 'client' where it matters, e.g. when it has two options for the same thing in server vs client roles.)
On the other hand, the term 'client' could be ambiguous in this case – for example, if the option were named allowed clients it would be not clear from context whether it would refer to a client at network level (identified by IP address) or a client at SMB level (identified by username) or some other criteria (version? vendor? NetBIOS name?). Calling it allowed hosts makes it clearer that the option expects some kind of host-level identifier, generally an IP address.
